Django REST Framework MultiPartParser parsing JSON as string
I am making a django functional based view where the request contains some JSON and a file.
Using DRF's MultiPartParser is parsing the JSON section of the request as a string.
what can I do to fix this?
here is the view:
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser

@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser])
def import_files(request: Request) -> Response:
    data = request.data
    print(type(data['json']))

    return Response("Success", status=200)

and here is the client request using python requests:
import requests
import json

multipart_payload = [
    ('json', (None, json.dumps(payload), 'application/json')),
    ('file', ('test.xlsx', open('test.xlsx', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'))
]

put_response = requests.post(endpoint + "feature/", files=multipart_payload)
print(put_response.json())

I have tried adding JSONParser to the @parser_classes decorator but it didn't work.
if anyone had a similar issue any help would be great thanks

Why not use multipart form data only here? I mean why do you want to use both json and form data. Another design would be to use a file upload endpoint and another endpoint for your json data. In other words file as a related model.

Describing the real world scenario this is going to be used in helps with suggesting an appropriate design.

@Ehsan88 The design I am going for is where the user can import a spreadsheet or a csv file and map the columns in the spreadsheet with the columns in the database

MultiPartParser is used to handle multipart/form-data and hence JSONParser which handles application/json may not work.
You may use the following:-
import json

@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser])
def import_files(request: Request) -> Response:
    data = request.data
    if 'json' not in data:
        return Response("Failure", status=400)
    
    json_data = json.loads(data['json'])
    print(type(json_data))    #Should give 'class <dict>'

    return Response("Success", status=200)

